# How can I monitor new IPv4 connections in C#

Tags: c#, ip, pid, etw

I need to monitor any new IPv4 connection made by a computer. The information I need is the process ID making the connection as well as the IP address the process is connecting to. I would need a callback function that gets called as soon as a new connection is discovered.

I have tried using ETW with Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-Network, but I only get integer representations of some daddr and saddr that I can't seem to map back to an IP address. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: have you played a bit with TraceEvent and the Microsoft-Windows-TCPIP provider? Does it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the `Microsoft-Windows-TCPIP` provider. You can use [TraceEvent](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Diagnostics.Tracing.TraceEvent) to create a Realtime session, and TraceEvent has a KernelSourceParser which allows you to parse for IP data

```
_kernelTraceEventParser = new KernelTraceEventParser(_source);
_kernelTraceEventParser.TcpIpConnect += KernelParserOnTcpIpConnect;



private void KernelParserOnTcpIpConnect(TcpIpConnectTraceData tcpIpConnectTraceData)
{
     lokalAddress = tcpIpConnectTraceData.saddr + ":" + tcpIpConnectTraceData.sport;
     serverAddress = tcpIpConnectTraceData.daddr + ":" + tcpIpConnectTraceData.dport;
}
```

Because `TcpIpConnectTraceData` is inherit from `TraceEvent` class you have access to ProcessName and ProcessID.

Comment: Is there any way to filter private data transfers?

Comment: I have no idea as I never tried this.

Answer (score 0):

The function you are seeking for is called [GetTcpTable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366026(v=vs.85).aspx), partial implementation in C# is [available here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4298/Getting-active-TCP-UDP-connections-on-a-box). The latter also obtains the process so it completely fulfills you requirements.

It also seems to be available without inter-op [as part of newer .NET implementations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.ipglobalproperties.getactivetcpconnections(v=vs.110).aspx).